# Looking for example of GORM / pgx connecting to postgres with Kerberos

Tags: go, kerberos, go-gorm, pgx

Been looking for an example or documentation leveraging kerberos with GORM or pgx, to connect to Postgres Db.

Found some references, on [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx)

```
import (
 "github.com/jackc/pgconn"
 "github.com/otan/gopgkrb5"
)

func init() {
  pgconn.RegisterGSSProvider(func() (pgconn.GSS, error) { return gopgkrb5.NewGSS() })
}
```

Thank you,
Bob

Been surfing for a bit, but cant seem to find anything that really explains what needs to be done to get the connection set.